# Find acceleration of a particle when given a velocity function in terms of displacement.

Tags: kinematics

Particle B moves such that its velocity $v\>ms^{-1}$ is related to its 
displacement $s\>$m, by the equation $v(s)=arcsin(\sqrt{s})$. Find 
the acceleration of particle B when $s=0.1 $m.

My attempt:

$
\frac{dv}{ds}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{s(1-s)}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{0.1(0.9)}}=\frac{5}{3}
$, but this is not the answer.

Comment: Acceleration is $dv/dt$, not $dv/ds$.

Comment: @zipirovich, I agree with you, so how do I proceed from here?

Comment: Hint: Chain rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Chain Rule:
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dv}{ds}\cdot\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{dv}{ds}\cdot v=\frac{\arcsin\left(\sqrt{s}\right)}{2s\sqrt{s(1-s)}},$$
and you can plug in now.